# How to calculate the average power of each frequency band?

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density, eeg

I have EEG data from 30 participants, each recording is about 3 mins, and I'm trying to calculate the average power of each frequency band.
I tried using Welch's or multitaper functions, but my values seem very odd. They are all extremely low. Can someone tell me if I implemented it correctly or what I did wrong?

My whole code and results can be found here: https://mne.discourse.group/t/calculate-spectral-density/4294

Thank you in advance!! I really just don't know what the problem is and I'm getting very desperate.

Comment: Why do you think they're extremely low? To me (not someone with a background in EEG, nor any knowledge about the data your EEG device delivers, whether it's calibrated etc), these are just numbers and do look somewhat plausible. You're a bit on the advantage here – you know about the medical background of these measurements and what you expect!

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but some thoughts and questions that don't fit in a comment

How is your data captured and calibrated. What unit's is it in?

> I’m expecting values between 5 and 20 Hz

Where is this expectation coming from? $Hz$ is unit of frequency not power spectral density.

> They are all extremely low.

Why do you think this? It's not unusual for the PSD of EEG signals to be in range of $nV/\sqrt{Hz}$ or $\mu V/\sqrt{Hz}$. Voltages in the brain are fairly low and electrodes are not particular efficient.

There are three different DFT scaling types ("standard" "power conserving" and "sine wave amplitude preserving"). Make sure your library uses the right one.

I recommend using standard debugging steps: start with a simple signal that you already know the answer for and verify every individual step of you code one by one.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! Apparently I had some conceptual issues here, I actually thought that I was calculating the PSDs, that's why I was expecting values between 5 - 20 for example. But I thought that that's what the multitaper function is for? to calculate the PSD? Do you know how calculate the PSDs now?